# Sumar valores de una lista multiplos de 3 y sumar sus valores

Tags: python

Necesito recorrer las siguientes listas y sumar sus valores por índice y si su resultado es múltiplo de mul (en este caso 3) sumar todas las sumas que sean múltiplos de mul en la lista.

```
import number_functions

numbers1 = [3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 8]
numbers2 = [2, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4]
mul = 3
suma = number_functions.sumar_multiplos(numbers1, numbers2, mul)
print(suma)
```

Mi código es el siguiente y el problema es que no coge todas las sumas, solamente coje la ultima suma (8 + 4 = 12) pero no la tercera (4 + 5 = 9). Alguna solución?

```
def sumar_multiplos(n1, n2, n):
for i in range(len(n1)):
    result = 0
    sum = n1[i] + n2[i]
    if sum % n == 0:
        result += sum
return result
```

Comment: mueve el `result = 0` arriba del `for`

Comment: Buenas solo tenías que sacar resultado=0 del bucle sino volvía su valor a 0 cada repetición.  Ya lo edité asi. Un saludo

Comment: @JavierFiestasBotella he rechazado tu edición por que intentas responder y para eso existe la sección de respuestas o la de comentarios, donde ya le he señalado el error.